# Latex PDF adds line for areas with low opacity

Tags: pdf, texstudio, line

I'm using TexStudio to write my thesis. However, when I use `includegraphics` to include some generated plots in pdf format, latex adds some contour lines to some areas. In the shown image the light blue thin line around the blue area in the background is wrong. When viewing the PDF with  adobe pdf viewer everything is fine.

Im working on Ubuntu 18.04 and TeXstudio 2.12.6.

Is anyone familiar with this problem and knows how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You mean that the extra lines are visible in the TeXStudio preview window? If the issue is not present in any other viewer then it is probably just a rendering artifact in TeXStudio, and then it is not really a problem because other people will not use TeXStudio to view your pdf.

Comment: you are right! it was just the preview, thanks!